# Implement date picker in button click and store in edit text

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am beginner to Android and trying to implement a date picker dialog in Android.

For that purpose I am studying this link: [Date Picker - Developers Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

So far I have understood but my requirement is when I click a `button` I need to get the date picker dialog and when I set the date picker I need to set the value in a `Edit Text`.

According to the link we need to extend `DialogFragment` and implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

Now my understanding to follow below process to achieve this:

1. Create a new XML with only date picker.
2. Create a Java file and implement the date picker code.
3. In parent class button click call the `Intent` to the `datepicker` class
4. Pass the value to the parent class `Edit Text`

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: implement what you have understood, come back with pointing out the problem in the code if you encounter one , think you have enough rep to understand that :)

Comment: @user2450263 yes... I understood that actually my problem is now I can't implement the code... that is the reason I have asked in advance so that if my queries are clarified I can directly implement what I need.

Comment: okay..pls elaborate "can't implement"

Comment: meanwhile, can check these: [one](http://androidexample.com/In_this_example_creating_a_date_picker_to_pick_day__month_year_of_date/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=89&aaid=113) and [two](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/datepicker/android-date-picker-example/)

Comment: I work in differet technology and this is my personal intrest to learn android... so I am practising it in my free time... my approach is before start or practising collect the data required and implement at once... Thanks for your examples

Comment: @user2450263 Thanks for your suggestion.. I was able to implement successfully by using your links and below accepted answer.. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code for that..

```
Button bt_setdate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_setdate);
bt_setdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            // get the current date

        }
    });
```

and outside onCreate()

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
          //Edit------------------------------------------//
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       //Edit------------------------------------------//
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
        String selmonth=cm.getMonth(month);

        bookingdate=String.valueOf(year)+"-"+String.valueOf(month)+"-"+String.valueOf(day);

    }
};
```

`bookingdate` contains the date that is selected..
and add this to your layout

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: thatnks for your reply... but in the parent activity I don't want the datepicker to be visible... I want it to be visible only after button is clicked

Comment: i've edited the code..see it..use `android:visibility="gone"`

Comment: thanks for the code... will accept as answer once I implement

Comment: Sorry for coming back to you late... but your code is not working and throwing a null pointer exception at `return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                year, month,day);`. can you please guide me here

Comment: your solution worked for me but there is a small edit.. that I made to your solution then it worked... Thanks

Comment: Now can you please tell me how to know inside my ondataset that whether user has clicked on positive button or not ?? because if user clicked positive button then i want to call a function of mine. Please reply must hav been stuck in this problem since last two days ??

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener                date;
Calendar                                          myCalendar;
dob_add_emp             = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob_add_emp);

myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};

dob_add_emp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (dob_add_emp.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            new DatePickerDialog(AddEmployee.this, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String dob = dob_add_emp.getText().toString();
            String[] d = dob.split("-");

            new DatePickerDialog(AddEmployee.this, date, Integer.parseInt(d[0]), Integer.parseInt(d[1]) - 1, Integer.parseInt(d[2]))
                    .show();
        }
    }
});



@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")

private void updateLabel()
{
    try


{
    // String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; // In which you need put here
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date current_date = new Date();
    Date session_date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    int difference = current_date.compareTo(session_date);
    if (difference == 0)
    {
        dob_add_emp.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
    else if (difference < 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select date before current date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        dob_add_emp.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: @Siva let me know if any error bcz this code working fine on my projects.

Comment: Now can you please tell me how to know inside my ondataset that whether user has clicked on positive button or not ?? because if user clicked positive button then i want to call a function of mine. Please reply must hav been stuck in this problem since last two days ??

Answer (score 0):

Hi plz use the code on click of button where you wanna open date picker dialog

```
 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
 private int year;
 private int month;
 private int day;

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

btnDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }
 });
```

add following methods to your activity as

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    // set date picker as current date
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
            day);
}
return null;
}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener =
                  new    DatePickerDialog.   OnDateSetListener(){

       // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
         year = selectedYear;
         month = selectedMonth;
         day = selectedDay;

         // set selected date into edittext
           txtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1).append("-")
            .append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));

        }
     };
```

you can format date as your reuirement..

Comment: Now can you please tell me how to know inside my ondataset that whether user has clicked on positive button or not ?? because if user clicked positive button then i want to call a function of mine. Please reply must hav been stuck in this problem since last two days ??

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.androidexample.datepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatePickerExample extends Activity {

    private TextView Output;
    private Button changeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
        changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeDate);

        // Get current date by calender

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Show current date

        Output.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        // Button listener to show date picker dialog

        changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // On button click show datepicker dialog 
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

            }

        });
   }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog. 
            // set date picker for current date 
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date 
            Output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

           }
        };

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click To Change Date" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current/Selected Date (M-D-YYYY): "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now can you please tell me how to know inside my ondataset that whether user has clicked on positive button or not ?? because if user clicked positive button then i want to call a function of mine. Please reply must hav been stuck in this problem since last two days ??